# Call to undefined method PHPExcel::sheetNameExists() When Loading a Template Excel File

Tags: phpexcel

I am trying to load an excel template:

```
require_once BASEPATH .'libraries/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filename);
```

and it throws an Error:

```
Call to undefined method PHPExcel::sheetNameExists() in ...\libraries\PHPExcel\Worksheet.php on line 809
```

I checked `$filename` and the file is existing.

**Spec:**

**PHPExcel:** v. 1.7.6, 2011-02-27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely mixing PHPExcel versions. The latest stable version is PHPExcel 1.8.0, and was released in March 2014. The missing function, `PHPExcel::sheetNameExists()`, is defined in PHPExcel.php.

PHPExcel_1.8.0_doc.zip contains a folder named Classes, inside it there's a folder named PHPExcel and a file named PHPExcel.php. You need to copy both to your libraries folder.

Download the latest PHPExcel version at https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: I have no way of checking this now since I switched projects, probably you are right. :)